# Nginx Rewrite Rule for all .PHP files/requests to be parsed by index.php

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Is it any magic rewrite (like it does on Apache) for nginx to be able to rewrite URLs like '/submit.php' to be able to process them from index.php? We have lots of 404 not found errors because of the site structure and all previous URLs were like '/addrate.php', '/my_settings.php', '/profile.php' --> there are over 50 files like this and it would be very unprofessional and code-unwise to create a separate .php file for each of these functions, instead of parsing them all through index.php and using the needed classes like we do with the other rewrites.

Can you please find a solution/give us a suggestion today about this?

I think some info about this is here, but I want the exact reversed result:
http://www.nullis.net/weblog/2011/05/nginx-rewrite-remove-file-extension/

Answer (score 1):

This configuration allow you to handle all URL (non-existing files in file system) with one php script placed in `/var/www/example.org/htdocs/index.php`

```
server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4

    server_name  example.org www.example.org;
    root            /var/www/example.org/htdocs;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/example.org.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/example.org.error.log;

    location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    # enable running php files under php fastcgi
    location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.org/htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING $uri;
            include fastcgi_params1;
    }

    location @php {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/example.org/htdocs/index.php; # this script catches all non existing URLs
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING $uri;
            include fastcgi_params1;
    }
}
```